# pandas xlsxwriter, format table header - not sheet header

Tags: python, excel, pandas, format, xlsxwriter

I'm saving pandas DataFrame to_excel using xlsxwriter. I've managed to format all of my data (set column width, font size etc) except for changing header's font and I can't find the way to do it. Here's my example:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'test_data': [1,2,3,4,5]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test', index=False)

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['test']

font_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_name': 'Arial', 'font_size': 10})
header_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_name': 'Arial', 'font_size': 10, 'bold': True})

worksheet.set_column('A:A', None, font_fmt)
worksheet.set_row(0, None, header_fmt)

writer.save()
```

The penultimate line that tries to set format for the header does nothing.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I think you need first reset default header style, then you can change it:

```
pd.core.format.header_style = None
```

All together:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({'test_data': [1,2,3,4,5]})
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('test.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

pd.core.format.header_style = None

data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='test', index=False)

workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['test']

font_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_name': 'Arial', 'font_size': 10})
header_fmt = workbook.add_format({'font_name': 'Arial', 'font_size': 10, 'bold': True})

worksheet.set_column('A:A', None, font_fmt)
worksheet.set_row(0, None, header_fmt)

writer.save()
```

Explaining by [jmcnamara](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694313/pandas-xlsxwriter-format-header/36694513?noredirect=1#comment60978389_36694513), thank you:

In Excel a cell format overrides a row format overrides a column format.The `pd.core.format.header_style` is converted to a format and is applied to each cell in the header. As such the default cannot be overridden by `set_row()`. Setting `pd.core.format.header_style` to `None` means that the header cells don't have a user defined format and thus it can be overridden by `set_row()`.

EDIT: In version `0.18.1` you have to change

```
pd.core.format.header_style = None
```

to:

```
pd.formats.format.header_style = None
```

EDIT: from version 0.20 this changed again

```
import pandas.io.formats.excel
pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None
```

thanks [krvkir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36694313/pandas-xlsxwriter-format-header/36694513?noredirect=1#comment62459317_36694513).

EDIT: from version 0.24 this is now required

```
import pandas.io.formats.excel
pandas.io.formats.excel.ExcelFormatter.header_style = None
```

thanks [Chris Vecchio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58033197/1746630).

Comment: This answer should be updated to reflect the contribution by Chris Vecchio below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58033197/8146556

Answer (score 32):

An update for anyone who comes across this post and is using Pandas 0.20.1.

It seems the required code is now

```
import pandas.io.formats.excel
pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None
```

Apparently the `excel` submodule isn't imported automatically, so simply trying `pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None` alone will raise an `AttributeError`.

Answer (score 25):

Another option for Pandas 0.25 (probably also 0.24). Likely not the best way to do it, but it worked for me.

```
import pandas.io.formats.excel
pandas.io.formats.excel.ExcelFormatter.header_style = None
```

Answer (score 6):

**for pandas 0.24:**

The below doesn't work anymore:

```
import pandas.io.formats.excel
pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None
```

Instead, create a cell formatting object, and re-write the first row's content (your header) one cell at a time with the new cell formatting object.
Now, you are future proof.

Use the following pseudo code:

```
# [1] write df to excel as usual
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(path_output, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name, index=False)

# [2] do formats for other rows and columns first

# [3] create a format object with your desired formatting for the header, let's name it: headercellformat

# [4] write to the 0th (header) row **one cell at a time**, with columnname and format
for columnnum, columnname in enumerate(list(df.columns)):
    worksheet.write(0, columnnum, columnname, headercellformat)
```

Comment: This is the recommended way according to docs (https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/example_pandas_header_format.html). AND, it prevents from formatting the whole row (up to XFD column)

Answer (score 5):

In pandas 0.20 the solution of the accepted answer changed again.

The format that should be set to None can be found at:

```
pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style
```

Answer (score 1):

If you do not want to set the header style for pandas entirely, you can alternatively also pass a `header=False` to `ExcelWriter`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(3, 5), 
                  columns=pd.date_range('2019-01-01', periods=5, freq='M'))

file_path='output.xlsx'
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(file_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', header=False, index=False )
workbook = writer.book
fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': 'mm/yyyy', 'bold': True})
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']
worksheet.set_row(0, None, fmt)
writer.save()
```

Answer (score -1):

unfortunately add_format is in not avaiable anymore