# Python Pandas Error: AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'formats'

Tags: python, pandas

I have 0.20.3 version of pandas install. I am trying to set header_style to false so that i can format the header row. [xlsxwriter not applying format to header row of dataframe - Python Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41447606/xlsxwriter-not-applying-format-to-header-row-of-dataframe-python-pandas)

I keep getting error : AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'formats'

I have tried

```
pd.formats.format.header_style = None
```

and

```
pd.core.format.header_style = None
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the API, the module pandas.formats and pandas.core.format do not exist : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html
It is normal that you have this error.

If you read new API changes with 0.20, pandas.formats has become pandas.io.formats. Try to check the API.

Comment: that's perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this, [suggested by @Martin Evans](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45955710/10238), is to write the headers directly, outside of Pandas. This avoids issues like above with different Pandas versions.

See also this example in the [XlsxWriter docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-headers).

Comment: Great. Thanks for the link. I will try it out.