# merging multiple .txt files into one .xlsx having different column names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter, xlrd

I've been following this answer : [How do I extract data from multiple text files to Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48772006/how-do-i-extract-data-from-multiple-text-files-to-excel-using-python-one-file) for merging multiple `.txt` files to one `.xlsx` spreadsheet, but this answer is giving me the data in multiple worksheets with no distinct column names.

What I'm trying to do is to extract the data of 3 `.txt` files(each file contains data in one column without a column name) into one spreadsheet and each column should have a distinct column name('col1', 'col2' and 'col3') respectively.

data1.txt:

```
ACC_NT/mc_pf_qer
ACC_NT/gsd
ACC_NT/hcv_efg_tdc
ACC_NT/ids_gc
ISQ_BX/oic_lkv
ISQ_BX/pfg_8c
```

data2.txt:

```
79.2%
53.9%
100.0%
50.0%
44.2%
0.0%
```

data3.txt:

```
ACC_NT/ACC_NT_mc_pf_qer.html
ACC_NT/ACC_NT_gsd.html
ACC_NT/ACC_NT_hcv_efg_tdc.html
ACC_NT/ACC_NT_ids_gc.html
ISQ_BX/ISQ_BX_oic_lkv.html
ISQ_BX/ISQ_BX_pfg_8c.html
```

Any help or guidance is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You should always include your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC:

```
data = {}
for i, filename in enumerate(['data1.txt', 'data2.txt', 'data3.txt'], 1):
    data[f"col{i}"] = pd.read_csv(filename, squeeze=True, header=None)
pd.concat(data, axis=1).to_excel('output.xlsx')
```

**Update**

> I realized that the col2 data contains the percentage details and in the output.xlsx

```
data = {}
for i, filename in enumerate(['data1.txt', 'data2.txt', 'data3.txt'], 1):
    data[f"col{i}"] = pd.read_csv(filename, squeeze=True, header=None)
df = pd.concat(data, axis=1)
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.strip('%').astype(float)
df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Many thanks for the answer!!! what if i don't want the first column (which i believe represents the index values) from the generated `output.xlsx` ?

Comment: Use `to_excel(... , index=False)`

Comment: I realized that the `col2` data contains the percentage details and in the output.xlsx ,it has appeared as `str`...i found that `pandas` as `.astype` feature to convert the  `col` datatype, but not sure how i can apply that feature here to convert `col2` to `int`....?

Comment: It's better with the sample. Can you check my answer?

Comment: Yup, finally done...many thanks :-)