# xlsxwriter changes the font style to bold for the first column within an excel document. How to disable this option?

Tags: python, pandas

One of these two openpyxl, xlsxwriter changes automatically the font style to bold when exporting an csv file to excel. It happens only for the first column. Do you know why and how can i overcome this behavior ?

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import xlsxwriter
from pandas import DataFrame
import time
from glob import iglob

 data = pd.read_csv(next(iglob('*.csv')))
 data = data.sort_values(by=['A'], ascending=False)
 data.to_excel('out.xlsx',engine='xlsxwriter', index=False)
```

Comment: Just to note as a clarification that it is Pandas that is adding the bold format to the header via openpyxl or xlsxwriter. to specify your own header see this example: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-headers

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a custom [`pd.ExcelWriter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html#pandas.ExcelWriter) instance to [`pd.DataFrame.to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) and explicitly disable any styles on the header column:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col_a': [1,2,3,4], 'col_b': [5,6,7,8]})

with pd.ExcelWriter('out.xlsx') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, index=False)

    workbook  = writer.book
    worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

    header_format = workbook.add_format({
        'bold': False,
        'border': False})

    for col_num, value in enumerate(df.columns.values):
        worksheet.write(0, col_num, value, header_format)
```

**Edit [no longer supported in pandas 0.24]**: alternatively, you can [reset all pandas default header styling](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36694513/3423035). Afterwards, just call `df.to_excel()` as usual.

```
import pandas.io.formats.excel
pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None
```

Comment: Pandas 0.24 doesn't support anymore pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None. Now, regarding to your code, my csv file could contain from 2 to 30 columns, for which i don't know the name. How to translate this into python ?

Comment: @Jan Trienes That `header_style = None` workaround isn't recommended since the location of the format changed in different versions of pandas. Your `enumerate` approach in the sample code is preferable. See also: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html#formatting-of-the-dataframe-headers

Comment: @bogdann Thanks! The solution involving `workbook.add_format` should still work, though. What do you mean with _"my csv file could contain from 2 to 30 columns, for which i don't know the name?"_

Comment: Sorry, i've got it! Runs perfect now. Thank you!

Comment: @bogdann good to hear! Consider accepting the answer if it helped :)