# Pandas 0.24 core header style not working

Tags: python, pandas

**for pandas 0.24:**

The below doesn't work anymore:

```
import pandas.io.formats.excel
pandas.io.formats.excel.header_style = None
```

anyone has any solution in the same way as above, as workaround works sometimes for static things, not for all.

Please check if someone has any solution.

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55666917/2901002)

Comment: @jezrael thanks for sharing, this is working. curious to know, if its full proof?

Comment: I hope so. Because to many changes here ;)